# Python Lambda Network Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

Yesterday I started developing a serverless application in AWS including python lambdas. After testing my code I wasn't able to save it.

Normally after pressing "Save" the button changes the color to white/grey, but it stays orange. In the Top it says "network error":

[image: After trying to save the lambda script]

After quitting the function I cannot even save/create/change any python script.

[image: after trying to create an lambda]

It looks like its just an problem with my AWS account, since my business account is working properly

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this error today, and it seems unlikely the glitch wouldn't have been resolved one week later if AWS knew about it.

This was encountered using Brave, which apparently Amazon doesn't support since I then switched to a Chromium incognito session and it worked for me there. If you're already using a mainstream browser like Chrome/Chromium or Firefox, check you don't have any extensions that may be interfering.

I'm guessing you opened your Enterprise account in a different browser to the AWS account where you are encountering the problem.

Comment: Hey, i tried disabling all my Extensions and you are right. After removing some extensions and clearing the Brwoser settings etc. It works. Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try again, it’s 99.9% likely it was just a temporary network glitch. Maybe `Ctrl+F5` to force a complete page reload.

Comment: I already tried that. Also trief restarting computer. Relogging and so on did not worked

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem with solution from boltronics, whic turn off all extension or widget on your browser first before create a lambda function